# Atmega328p ADC - value keeps returning zero when connected

Tags: avr, atmega, atmega328p, avr-gcc

I'm currently try to connect a DS18S20 temperature sensor to the atmega328p. I have wired AVCC and AGRD to the same power rail on my breadboard as normal VCC/GRD and AREF is not connected.

When I try to connect the data pin of the temperature sensor to the first channel of port A, the value changes to zero and stays zero. Before connecting the data pin, the value jumps around randomly. I have the following code:

```
volatile uint16_t vOutADCReading = 0U;

void setupAnalogDigitalConversion(){
  ADMUX |= 1<<REFS0;
  ADCSRA |= 1<<ADEN;
  ADCSRA |= 1<<ADPS0 | 1<<ADPS1 | 1<<ADPS2;
  ADCSRA |= ( 1 << ADSC );
}

void adc_read(uint8_t channel){
  ADMUX &= 0xf0;
  ADMUX |= channel;
  ADCSRA |=  (1<<ADSC);

  while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF));
  // Set voltage output
  vOutADCReading = ADC;
  // Clear ADIF flag
  ADCSRA |= ( 1 << ADIF );
  _delay_ms(1000);
}

void main(){
  while(1){
    adc_read(0);
    displayOnSegmentDisplay(vOutADCReading);
    _delay_ms(1000);
  }

}
```

Are there any errors in this code?

Comment: DS18S20 outputs digital signal. If you attempt to read it with ADC you will only see ones and zeroes -> https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/sensors/DS18S20.html .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DS18x20 series are digital thermometers using the One-Wire protocol on their data pin. Look up any of the Dallas/Maxim DS18b20 libraries to use this one.

If, on the other had, you want an analog thermo-sensor, try the LM34/LM35 series of analog sensors (Fahrenheit/Celsius, respectively) which put voltage, proportional to temperature, on their data pin.